# Karma xml report

Tags: unit-testing, junit, jasmine, karma-runner

I use `karma` and `jasmine` to test frontend in my project. Test results saves with `karma-junit-reporter` plugin. Now testcases are grouping by testsuites according to browser. But I want to group testcases according to its `describe` sections. For report this, jasmine has an `suiteStarted` and `suiteDone` methods. How to use they in `karma` environment and create report in my form?
As far as I noticed, now karma-jasmine-adapter doesn't report about these events to karma-backend, and this should be overcome someway